# Доступ к объекту mysqli из функций

Tags: mysqli, php

Доброго вам времени суток товарищи! Раньше пользовался устаревшим модулем **mysql**, теперь переписывая свою **CMS** перехожу на **mysqli** и возникает сразу вопрос :

Как в функции **f1()** использовать открытое соединение с **mysql** т.е. **$link?** Не передавать же по ссылке, и не открывать новое.

Знаю, что можно вызывать **mysqli_query**, но процедуре нужен **$link**.

Со старым модулем **mysql** было проще, открыл вначале, пользуюсь не обращаясь к **$link**.

```
<?php
$link   =   new mysqli('данные для подключения');
#
function f1() {
    //здесь надо отправить запрос в базу
}
#
f1();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать банальный синглтон и радоваться... Вот пример, пользуйтесь:

```
<?php
/**
 * Database module
 *
 */

/**
 * M_Core_DB
 *
 * @uses $db = M_Core_DB::getInstance();
 * First use: $db = M_Core_DB::getInstance(array('host'=>'localhost','login'=>'root','password'=>'root','db'=>'test', 'type'=>'mysqli' or 'mysql'));
 */
class M_Core_DB{

    /**
     * Module Instance for Singleton pattern
     *
     * @var M_Core_DB
     */
    static private $instance = null;

    /**
     * Singleton main method
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return M_Core_DB
     */
    static function getInstance($params = false){
        if (self::$instance == null){
            self::$instance = new M_Core_DB($params);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Mysqli connection handler
     *
     * @var mysqli
     */
    public $handler = null;

    /**
     * Mysqli statement handler
     *
     * @var mysqli_stmt
     */
    protected $stmt = null;

    /**
     * Mysql result handler
     * 
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $result = null;

    /**
     * Stmt result keys
     *
     * @var arrays
     */
    protected $keys = array();
    /**
     * Stmt metadata
     *
     * @var mysqli_metadata
     */

    /**
     * Database connect type
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $meta = null;

    /**
     * Module constructor
     *
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function __construct($params = false){
        if ($params && $params['type'] == 'mysqli')
            $this->connect_mysqli($params);
        if ($params && $params['type'] == 'mysql')
            $this->connect_mysql($params);
        $this->type = $params['type'];
        if (array_key_exists('encoding',$params)) $this->query("set names ".$params['encoding']); else $this->query("set names UTF8");
    }

    /**
     * Connect to database - mysqli method
     *
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function connect_mysqli($params){
        if (!$params) throw new Exception('Params error');
        if (!$this->handler = new mysqli($params['host'],$params['login'],$params['password'],$params['db'])) throw new Exception(mysqli_error());
    }

    /**
     * Connect to database - mysql method
     *
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function connect_mysql($params){
        if (!$params) throw new Exception('Params error');
        if (!$this->handler = mysql_connect($params['host'],$params['login'],$params['password'])) throw new Exception('Error connectind to database server');
        if ($this->handler) {
            if (!mysql_select_db($params['db'], $this->handler)) throw new Exception('Error selecting database');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send query
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @param mixed(string,array) $params
     */
    public function query($query, $params = false){
        if ($this->type == 'mysql')
            return $this->query_mysql($query, $params);
        if ($this->type == 'mysqli')
            return $this->query_mysqli($query, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Send query - mysqli
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @param mixed(string,array) $params
     */
    public function query_mysqli($query, $params = false){
        $this->stmt = $this->handler->prepare($query);
        if (!$this->stmt){
            throw new Exception(mysqli_error($this->handler)."\n\n".$query); 
        }
        if ($params){
            if (!is_array($params)) $params = array($params);
            array_unshift($params, str_repeat('s', count($params)));
            $refs = array();
            foreach ($params as $i => &$f) $refs[$i] = &$f;
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this->stmt, 'bind_param'),$refs);
        }
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $this->stmt->close();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Send query - mysqli
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @param mixed(string,array) $params
     */
    public function query_mysql($query, $params = false){
        if ($params !== false) {
            if (!is_array($params))
                $params = array($params);
            $arQuery = explode('?', $query);
            if (count($arQuery) - 1 != count($params))
                throw new Exception('Wrong count of arguments');
            $query = $arQuery[0];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++) {
                switch(gettype($params[$i])) {
                    case  'string': $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($params[$i], $this->handler)."'".$arQuery[$i + 1];
                                    break;  
                    case 'integer': $query .= intval($params[$i]).$arQuery[$i + 1];
                                    break; 
                    case  'double': $query .= doubleval($params[$i]).$arQuery[$i + 1];
                                    break;
                    case 'boolean': $query .= (($params[$i])?1:0).$arQuery[$i + 1];
                                    break;
                    case    'NULL': $query .= intval(0).$arQuery[$i + 1];
                                    break;
                           default: throw new Exception('Wrong type of arguments');
                }
            }
        }
        $this->result = mysql_query($query, $this->handler);
        //echo $query."\n";
        return $this->result;
    }

    /**
     * Execute query
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @param mixed(string,array) $params
     */
    public function _execute($query,$params = false){
        $this->stmt = $this->handler->prepare($query);
        if (!$this->stmt){
            throw new Exception(mysqli_error($this->handler)."\n\n".$query); 
        }
        if ($params){
            if (!is_array($params)) $params = array($params);
            array_unshift($params, str_repeat('s', count($params)));
            $refs = array();
            foreach ($params as $i => &$f) $refs[$i] = &$f;
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this->stmt, 'bind_param'),$refs);
        }
        $this->stmt->execute();

        $this->meta = $this->stmt->result_metadata();
        $this->keys = array();
        foreach ($this->meta->fetch_fields() as $col) $this->keys[] = $col->name;
        $this->stmt->store_result();
    }

    /**
     * Fetch results
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetch(){
        $values = array_fill(0, count($this->keys), null);
        $refs = array();
        foreach ($values as $i => &$f) $refs[$i] = &$f;

        call_user_func_array(array(&$this->stmt, 'bind_result'),$refs);
        $retval = $this->stmt->fetch();
        if (!$retval){
            $this->stmt->reset();
            return $retval;
        }
        return array_combine($this->keys, $refs);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all results
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @param mixed(string,array) $params
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetchAll($query,$params = false){
        if ($this->type == 'mysqli') {
            $this->_execute($query,$params);

            $data = array();
            while ($row = $this->fetch()){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        if ($this->type == 'mysql') {
            $ret = array();
            if ($this->query($query, $params))
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->result))
                    $ret[] = $row;
            else
                throw new Exception('Error fetching data');
            return $ret;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch one column
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @param mixed(string,array) $params
     * @return string
     */
    public function fetchOne($query, $params = false){
        if ($this->type == 'mysqli') {
            $this->_execute($query,$params);

            $this->stmt->bind_result($result);
            $this->stmt->fetch();
            $this->stmt->reset();
            return $result;
        }
        if ($this->type == 'mysql') {
            if ($this->query($query, $params))
                $ret = mysql_fetch_row($this->result);
            else
                throw new Exception('Error fetching data');
            return $ret[0]; 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Result num rows
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function num_rows(){
        if ($this->type == 'mysqli')
            return $this->stmt->num_rows();
        if ($this->type == 'mysql')
            return mysql_num_rows($this->handler);
    }

    /**
     * Last inserted id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function lastInsertId(){
        if ($this->type == 'mysqli')
            return $this->handler->insert_id;
        if ($this->type == 'mysql')
            return mysql_insert_id($this->handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$link   =   new mysqli('данные для подключения');
function f1() {
   global $link;
   $link->query( "SHOW DATABASES" );
}
f1();
?>
```

Comment: Но лучше все же пользоваться всеми возможностями языка и сделать класс.

Comment: Хорошо, а если объект mysqli будет объявлен в функции, а нужно получить к нему доступ в функции, которая находится в первой?

function x() {
 $link = new mysqli();
 #
 function d() {
  //здесь нужен объект mysqli
 }
}